# How to verify .plist and .kext files are legitimate?

Tags: malware, audit, forensics, macos

While scouring through tons of logs generated during an audit of a Mac filesystem after a potential malware infection, and I am wondering if there are any better ways to verify that all kernel extension (.kext) and property list (.plist) files are legitimate?

So far, I have just been doing `cat auditlog.txt | grep -v com.apple` so that I'm only looking at third party extensions. This filters out the vast majority of results, leaving only the files that aren't signed by Apple, but I have a feeling there is a better method.

Comment: I hope you are not considering just keeping your OS, you should reinstall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only good solution for recovering from a malware infection is to wipe the disk and reinstall the OS. If you have a backup that you are confident predates the infection, you can go back to that.

I know that you state that it's a *potential* malware infection, but if you have any doubts (which you obviously do as you asked this question), wipe the disk.

Comment: That's the plan, and I agree completely. This was my first recommendation to the computer's owner. At this point, I'm doing retroactive forensics just to see if I can discover anything interesting.